# How to set up an email on DigitalOcean for my domain?

Tags: email, digital-ocean

I'm trying to setup an email network on DigitalOcean for my domain xxx.com, so my email would look something like no-reply@xxx.com. Is that possible on DigitalOcean? I bought the domain on namecheap.com. If not, what other emailing possibilities are there for nodejs, i have tried sendgrid, but my emails are not getting delivered, because some yahoo users complained about spam.

Right now I'm using sendgrid, but my emails are not getting delivered, due to user complaints. My delivery email is from yahoo.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an article how to setup own mail server here: 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassassin